# Python tkinter navigation using grids

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to navigate between two simple pages:-

Page 1:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(230,300)

root.title("Page1")

label = tk.Label(root,text="File Path")
textBox = tk.Text(root,height=2,width=10)
textBox.config(state='disabled')
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Page 2:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(230,300)

root.title("Page2")

label = tk.Label(root,text="File Path")
textBox = tk.Text(root,height=2,width=10)
textBox.config(state='disabled')
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

I have searched for some solution but they involve hiding buttons using the `pack` methods which give me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store the pages in a list and use `grid_forget` to hide the previous page and use `page[index].grid` to bring the next page.

In your case, you are switching between two Text Widgets so store those widgets in a list.

here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def previousPage():
    global index
    if index > 0:
        pages[index].grid_forget()
        index -= 1
        msg = index
        pages[index].grid(row=1, column=1)

    else:
         msg = 'No more previous pages'

    lbl.config(text=msg)

def nextPage():
    global index

    if index < len(pages)-1:
        pages[index].grid_forget()
        index += 1
        msg = index
        pages[index].grid(row=1, column=1)
        
    else:
        msg = 'Last Page Reached'

    lbl.config(text=msg)

    
root = tk.Tk()

root.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

index = 0

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)

tk.Label(frame1, text='Hello').pack()
tk.Text(frame1, state='disabled').pack()

frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Label(frame2, text='Welcome').pack()
tk.Entry(frame2).pack()

pages = [frame1, frame2]

pages[0].grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.Button(root, text='Next', command= nextPage).grid(row=2, column=2)
tk.Button(root, text='Previous', command= previousPage).grid(row=2, column=0)

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=f'Page: {index}')
lbl.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However the code I provided is just an example.. I have other different elements like textbox as well on unique pages

Comment: Thank you, exactly what  I need. Do you also know how I can set constant screen size throughout? I did  root.minsize(400,0) however now my elements are centered, but I want them to be anchored to left